# AS3.0 wait until tween has finished

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, tween

When I click my button I wish one of mc's disapear completely(first alpha changes from 1 to 0) then removeChild.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
main.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);

function buttonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
{

var aBlend = new Tween(main, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 3, true);

aBlend.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, end);   //doesnt work
}
function end()
{
    this.removeChild(mc);
}
```

I dicided to use events but it doesnt work, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the aBlend declaration outside of the buttonClickHandler as suggested by this post:

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?s=e4e6512ae627e7810c4e991691324b9f&p=735466&postcount=4

i.e.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
main.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);

var aBlend;

function buttonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
{

aBlend = new Tween(main, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 3, true);

aBlend.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, end);   //doesnt work
}
function end(event:TweenEvent)
{
    this.removeChild(mc);
}
```

Comment: But when I declare Tween out of buttonClickHandler scope the tween is played on start of the movie instead of event MouseEvent.CLICK

Comment: Try again. I've added the TweenEvent arg to your event listeners.

Comment: Yes I came up with it also. Sorry for my mismatch. Thanks for help.